# How do I return a result for one column that is being filtered out by the other columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know my question is confusing, so let's just say let me try to explain with this code and picture below:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT DISTINCT
  r.JobNo,
  ROUND(r.TotEstHrs, 2) AS TotEstHrs,
  SUM(ROUND(t.ManHrs, 2)) AS ManHrs
FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderRouting r ON r.JobNo = t.JobNo AND r.WorkCntr 
= 'Assembly'
WHERE CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, 
GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
  AND CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATE) < DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), 
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
  AND t.PiecesFinished = 1
  AND t.WorkCntr IN ('150')
  AND ROUND(t.ManHrs*60, 2) > 15
GROUP BY r.JobNo, ROUND(r.TotEstHrs, 2)
ORDER BY r.JobNo
```

[image]

So I want to return only the items that were finished this week (i.e. that have a 1 in the PiecesFinished column).  However, I want to be able to sum all the ManHrs for that finished piece.  So for example, job 20139-01 was finished this week, however, it was worked on last week as well, it just wasn't finished until this week.  I want to be able to capture that information in my ManHrs column.  So if you look at 20139-01 in my Desired vs What I'm Getting tables, you'll see that in the ManHrs column, I'm only able to return 1.5 ManHrs for that job, because my code is only summing where PiecesFinished = 1 for this week, the .25 ManHrs is filtered out by both criteria in the Where clause, so I'm unable to capture that time in my result.

I tried doing a subquery, but that didn't work, I was thinking maybe a self-join would work, but I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around this, hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethint like this:

```
with cte AS(
select JobNo,
       sum(ManHrs)
from TimeTicketDet t1
where exists (select * 
              from TimeTicketDet t2
              where t2.JobNo = t1.JobNo and t2.PiecesFinished = 1)     
group by JobNo
)

select t.*, r.TotEstHrs
from cte t join OrderRouting r
       N r.JobNo = t.JobNo AND r.WorkCntr = 'Assembly';
```

Comment: Finally figured it out after spending about an hour on it.  You're answer definitely guided me in the right way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderRouting', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #OrderRouting;

CREATE TABLE #OrderRouting (
    WorkCntr VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    JobNo CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    TotEstHrs DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #OrderRouting (WorkCntr, JobNo, TotEstHrs) VALUES
    ('Assemply', '20139-01', 1.5),
    ('Assemply', '20139-02', 2.5),
    ('Assemply', '20139-03', 2.75),
    ('Assemply', '20139-04', 1),
    ('Assemply', '20139-05', 2);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TimeTicketDet', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TimeTicketDet;

CREATE TABLE #TimeTicketDet (
    TicketDate DATE NOT NULL,
    WorkCntr VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    JobNo CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    ManHrs DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
    PiecesFinished INT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TimeTicketDet (TicketDate, WorkCntr, JobNo, ManHrs, PiecesFinished) VALUES
    ('2017-08-31', 'Assembly', '20139-01', 0.25, 0),
    ('2017-09-08', 'Assembly', '20139-01', 1.5, 1),
    ('2017-09-05', 'Assembly', '20139-02', 1.75, 0),
    ('2017-09-08', 'Assembly', '20139-02', 0.5, 1),
    ('2017-09-08', 'Assembly', '20139-04', 1.25, 1);

--SELECT * FROM #OrderRouting oro;
--SELECT * FROM #TimeTicketDet ttd;

SELECT 
    oro.JobNo, 
    oro.TotEstHrs,
    tts.ManHrs
FROM
    #OrderRouting oro
    JOIN (
            SELECT 
                ttd.JobNo,
                ManHrs = SUM(ttd.ManHrs)
            FROM
                #TimeTicketDet ttd
            GROUP BY 
                ttd.JobNo
            ) tts
        ON oro.JobNo = tts.JobNo;
```

Results...

```
JobNo    TotEstHrs                               ManHrs
-------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
20139-01 1.50                                    1.75
20139-02 2.50                                    2.25
20139-04 1.00                                    1.25
```